# Moving ZFS rpool to smaller disks

Tags: 16.04, zfs

I installed ubuntu 16.04 following [this guide](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS) with 2 1TB disks. A few days back one of those disks failed and I am trying to recover from that.

I have 2 new disks, however these disks are smaller (500GB), so I can't simply put in the new disk and resilver, so I figured I'll need to setup a new pool and transfer.

I've tried transferring using

```
zfs send -R rpool@snapshot | zfs receive -F rpool2
```

after creating it using the guide above.

How to get GRUB to boot from this new pool?